# bash date: invalid date, invalid conversion

Tags: bash, whois

```
#!/bin/bash
DOM="onet.pl wp.pl"
for d in $DOM
do
  echo -n "$d - "
  whois $d | egrep -i 'Expiration|Expires on' | head -1
  # If you need list..
   whois $d | egrep -i 'Expiration|Expires on' | head -1 >> /tmp/domain.date
   expdate="$(whois $d | egrep -i 'Expiration|Expires on' | head -1)"
   #to seconds
   expdate="$(date -d"$expdate" +%s)"
   #current date
   curdate="$(date +%s)"
printf "Expiration date : $expdate\n"
printf "Current date : $curdate\n"
printf "Days for expiration : %s\n" "$(((expdate-curdate)/86400))"
 echo ""
done
```

And i get a result like this :

```
 onet.pl - option expiration date:       2019.08.16 16:52:03 
date: invalid date ‘option expiration date:       2019.08.16 16:52:03’
 Expiration date :
 Current date : 1524210803
 Days for expiration : -17641

 wp.pl - option expiration date:       2020.02.10 10:51:12 
date: invalid date ‘option expiration date:       2020.02.10 10:51:12’
 Expiration date :
 Current date : 1524210803 
Days for expiration : -17641
```

It looks like there is something wrong with date format, i was that maybe because of text+date instead of pure date. Because of that I believe the rest is not working properly. Any ideas how to make expiration date valid?

Comment: Add "set -x" to your script, and you can see the commands bash is running.

Comment: Note that, except if you are really only targeting a single whois server for ever, parsing whois servers in a generic fashion is not for the faint of heart for various reasons. If that is a need I recommend you to use some existing libraries that do that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!  Remove the `.` (dots) in your expiration date.  So do this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 expiration_date="2019.08.16 16:52:03"
 date -d"$(echo $expiration_date | tr -d '.')" +%s
```

The result command is thus:

```
date -d"20190816 16:52:03" +%s
```

and that is valid and proprely used by date -d.

This worked for me using **date (GNU coreutils) 8.25**, on Linux Mint 18 and **date (GNU coreutils) 8.4** on RHEL7.

Comment: You don't need `tr` for this, you can remove the dots with string replacement in the variable expansion: `date -d"${expiration_date//./}" +%s`

Comment: Yep, thanks, I always forget about these variable expansions.